# Choosing the clamp capacitor of active clamp forward

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, clamp

Does anyone know how to choose the Ccl value? Could you give me some suggestions?

[image]

I read these [Onsemi](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8273-D.PDF) and [TI](https://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/an/slua535a/slua535a.pdf?ts=1630744201468&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) documents.  The formula of Ccl are the same. I have some question about these two documents.

1. On TI page 24 equation (49), I don't understand why the resonant time constant is much greater than the maximum off-time.

[image]

2. On TI page 24 equation (50), how to get this formula and why need to multiply 10.

[image]

3. On Onsemi page 6 equation (15), how to get this formula.

[image]

Comment: The multiplying by ten is probably an attempt to find leakage inductance by dividing Lmag by ten. It's leakage inductance that causes unwanted flyback artefacts.

Comment: @Andyaka  I don't know what you mean, could you said more detail, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.) I don't understand why the resonant time constant is much greater than the maximum off-time.

The clamp capacitor charges up through the primary's magnetizing inductance and the clamp switch's body diode right after the main switch turns off and right before the clamp switch turns on.

The clamp capacitor discharges when the main switch is off and the clamp switch is on.

[image]

*The waveforms above are taken from [here](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/content/dam/toshiba-ss-v2/master/en/semiconductor/design-development/referencedesign/articles/active-clamp-forward-ac-dc_power_supply_rd157/RD157-RGUIDE-01_E.pdf).*

Here're the definitions of time sections:

A: Main switch on, clamp switch off (on-time)

B: Main switch off, clamp switch off (delay before clamp switch on, the resonant period)

C: Main switch off, clamp switch on (off-time)

D: Main switch off, clamp switch off (delay before on-time)

During the discharge of the clamp capacitor, this capacitor and the primary magnetizing inductance form an LC resonant tank and provides a resonant reset for the core.

As can be seen from the waveforms above, the voltage across the drain and source of the main switch has a resonant change during off time. Likewise, the drain current of the clamp switch has a resonant change as well.

We don't want the voltage across the main switch to change a lot (resonance, look at the waveforms above) as it may increase the losses and create a risk of destroying the main switch. For example, if the period of this resonance is lower than or equal to the off-time, the voltage across the drain-source of the main switch will be at least one period of sine-wave. Thus, the period of this resonance should be way higher than the off-time to maintain a constant-ish voltage across the main switch. So the resonance period of the LC tank should be higher than the off-time:

$$
\mathrm{
2\pi \ \sqrt{L_{mag}\ C_{CL}} > (T-T_{on})
}
$$

Remember that T is the sum of on-time (t<sub>on</sub>), off-time (t<sub>off</sub>) and a delay between these two (clamp capacitor's charge time). Thus, \$\mathrm{T >T_{on} + T_{off}}\$. Therefore the equation above turns into this:

$$
\mathrm{
2\pi \ \sqrt{L_{mag}\ C_{CL}} > T_{off}
}
$$

Note that this equation is no different than eq. 50 in the OP (without the multiplier of 10). And also note that the period should be high enough to provide enough time to core reset. Or else the core will saturate eventually.

> 2.) On TI page 24 equation (50), how to get this formula and why need to multiply 10.

The multiplier 10 probably is a safeguard to always hold the inequality above and guarantee a safe reset time. As you might already know, any mid- to hi-quality capacitor has at 10% tolerance at best. Considering this and the variations of the magnetizing inductance due to the winding and core properties *(i.e. the inductance tolerance can be 10% to 20% at best)*, a multiplier of 2 to 10 can be acceptable. Remember that higher values for clamp capacitance affect the step responses of the converter *(e.g. sudden load change or sudden line voltage change like surge)*.

> 3.) On Onsemi page 6 equation (15), how to get this formula.

This is a completely different story. It's not related to the clamp capacitor. It's a coupling capacitor to provide negative gate voltage for the PMOS, the clamp switch.

Comment: Hi Rohat, 

1.)Could you tell me, why the time constant of the LC tank should be higher than the off-time, why it can guarantee a proper reset.

Comment: @Jitter456 the core should be reset before the start of the next cycle, or else the core will saturate (Remember the BH loop and the loop's corresponding quarter where the ACF converter's transformer operates in).

Comment: I know the core should be reset, but I don't understand the time constant of the LC tank would be higher than off-time. What's the relation between them, if the time constant is smaller than off-time what's happened?

Comment: I hear the time constant of RC and RL, but I never hear time constant of LC, so I am very confused

Comment: @Jitter456 of course there's no such term as LC time constant. Sorry for the confusion. I meant the period of the LC circuit's resonance. Fixing it. The next comment will be an answer to your question.

Comment: Where I can find the next comment.

Comment: @Jitter456 editing my answer instead. Check back in a few minutes.

Comment: HI Rohat, 
Thanks, it is more clear to me, for the high side clamp is the same?

Comment: @Jitter456 Good. `for the high side clamp is the same?` yes.